# javaScript create checkBox dynamically and add event

Tags: javascript

I created check Box in javaScript:

```
var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
                    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
                    checkbox.name = "abc";
                    checkbox.addEventListener("onblur", saveNew("abc"));
                    checkbox.id = 1;
```

My problem is that he goes to saveNew function when he create the checkbox.
And I want that he will go only onblure.
How can I do it?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the event handler function which will be invoked when the event occurs.

```
checkbox.addEventListener("blur", function(){
   saveNew("abc");
});
```

Currently you are setting the return value of the function `saveNew("abc")`

Comment: thanks!
But it still doesn't go to saveNew function onblur.

Comment: @nom use `blur` instead of `onblur` you don't need to prefix `on` when using `addEventListener`